# convert namespace to module based typescript code

Tags: typescript

c# programmer here.
I started work on a medium sized ts code base. Modelled off an existing c# codebase. I started out doing

```
namespace Foo
{
    export function x;
    export const y;
    export class C1{}
}
```

for things that map to static classes and functions in c# and and 'real' classes

Foo being in one file called Foo.js. To call things I just said `Foo.x()` in a different file.

All fine, but more reading leads me to 'dont use namespaces'. So time for a refactor

I just want to make sure that I am doing the correct conversion. So now I do

```
export class Foo
{
    public x(){};
    public static readonly  y;
    public class C1{}
}
```

That replacement for const seems a mouthful. And when I call things I have to go

```
import {Foo} from "./Foo";
Foo.x();
```

So is this correct? Optimal?

Note - I want to keep the calling code doing `Foo.x(); var c = Bar.wibble;` etc. Ie really separate out the namespace of different functional parts

Answer (score 4):

Good news, you are making the conversion even harder on yourself than it needs to be. Instead of what you have written, try going for:

```
export function x() { /* ... */ }
export const y = /* ... */;
export class C1 { /* ... */ }
```

Then in your consuming files you can import only what you need:

```
import { x } from './Foo';
x();
```

Or if you want to continue to use it like a namespace you can:

```
import * as Foo from './Foo';
Foo.x();
```

In many cases you may be able to simply remove the wrapping `namespace` declaration and be done.

Comment: `import * as Foo from './Foo'` to really use it as a namespace.

Comment: i want to keep doing Foo.x not x in the calling code.

Comment: Updated answer to add in `* as Foo` syntax as well

Comment: this doesnt work well - so it seems. If I have 2 files both with function x in them they end up clashing

Comment: The only way there could be clashing is if you did `import { x } from './foo'; import { x } from './bar'`. You can always either import using `* as` format: `import * as Foo from './foo'; import * as Bar from './bar'`, or you can alias the imports `import { x as fooX } from './foo'; import { x as barX } from './bar'`